# Cant Change properties of a userControl because it doesnt show up as a variable from anot

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to c# and windows forms and I came across an error whilst trying to create a login page and I were wondering if you guys have any advice. The problem is that when I try to use a public variable that is defined in one class in a different class it says "The name 'loginPage' does not exist in the current context". "loginPage" is the name of a variable which is a Usercontrol defined in another class.

```
namespace CollegeDashboard
{
    partial class Dashboard
    {
       ...

        #endregion

        public Pages.LoginPages.LoginPage loginPage;//This is where "loginPage" is defined
    }
}
```

```
namespace CollegeDashboard.Pages.LoginPages
{
    public partial class LoginPage : UserControl
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loginPage//This is where "The name 'loginPage' does not exist in the current context" occurs
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried accessing the variable from another class but that didn't work and I have zero idea on what to try next, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It makes no sense in that context. If you want to access the current instance of your UC, use `this`

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context on what you are trying to do ?

Comment: You have initialized and instance of loginPage in class Dashboard, however you are trying to access that instance from within the LoginPage class it seems, the class LoginPage doesn't know about the object of it self in DashBoard.

Answer (score 1):

To reference a field, property or method of the `Dashboard` class from another class, you first need an instance of the `Dashboard` class. For example:

```
var myDashboard = new Dashboard();
var myLoginPage = myDashboard.loginPage;
// TODO: do something with myLoginPage
```

Edit: as per @BenVoight's comment, just creating a new instance immediately before you need it most likely isn't the correct solution, instead you need **an** instance, correctly initialised for whatever you want to do with it. And exactly how to do that will depend on exactly what you want to achieve.

My main point is that you need an instance of `Dashboard` in order to reference its members. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: "just create a new instance" is almost always the wrong solution to this problem.

Comment: True, I realise now that the answer could easily be read in the wrong way, hopefully my edit has corrected that